# Perform Monadic Computation N times

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm implementing a function to perform a monadic computation N times. I've written the following code.

```
performN :: Monad m => Int -> m t -> m [t]
performN 0 m = return []
performN n m = 
  do x1<- m
     x2<- if n == 1 then return [] else (m:performN (n-2) m)
     return (x1:x2)
```

I get the following error.

> :264:44: error:
>       • Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘[]’
>         ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>           the type signature for:
>             performN :: forall (m :: * -> *) t. Monad m => Int -> m t -> m [t]
>           at :260:13
>         Expected type: [m t]
>           Actual type: m [t]
>       • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘performN (n - 2) m’
>         In the expression: (m : performN (n - 2) m)
>         In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>           x2 <- if n == 1 then return [] else (m : performN (n - 2) m)
>       • Relevant bindings include
>           m :: m t (bound at :262:12)
>           performN :: Int -> m t -> m [t] (bound at :261:1)

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: `performN n-2 m` is `(performN n) - (2 m)`, not `performN (n - 2) m`. After fixing that, you'll probably want to drop the `m:` bit and change to subtracting one. And though I suppose you're doing this just as an exercise, it's [`replicateM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM).

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, edited the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got doing something zero times right.

```
performN :: Monad m => Int -> m t -> m [t]
performN 0 m = return []
```

And you've got the first part of doing something n times right: do it once.

```
performN n m = do
  x1 <- m
```

But then all you have to do is do it n − 1 more times. No strange `if` stuff.

```
performN n m = do
  x1 <- m
  x2 <- performN (n - 1) m
  return (x1 : x2)
```

Comment: Damn! Can't believe what I was thinking. :|
Thanks! :)

Comment: With applicatives: `liftA2 (:) m (performN (n - 1) m)`

Comment: Equivalently, `(:) <$> m <*> performN (n - 1)` is kinda nice because you don't need the explicit parens for grouping when the `(<*>)` operator can implicitly group. And if you use `pure` instead of `return`, you can generalize this to Applicative rather than requiring Monad.

Comment: @amalloy: Sure, but if we’re being practical and `Applicative`, it’d just be `replicateM` =) See comment on the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use this function, rather than needing to implement it for practice, you should just use [Control.Monad.replicateM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) instead of reimplementing it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Too much stuff. `n == 1`? `n-2`? Why? Simpler!

```
performN :: Monad m => Int -> m t -> m [t]
performN 0 _ = return []
performN n m =
  do x  <- m
     xs <- performN (n-1) m
     return $ x:xs
```